# Subadditivity of the limit superior

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

$$ \limsup \left(f(h)+g(h)\right) \leq \limsup f(h)+ \limsup g(h).$$

How can we prove this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $ h \in $ what?

Comment: Thomas, it is very rare for a thread on math.stackexchange to have no activity for 2 hours, plenty of us are willing to help you as long as you show us some effort and work you have done!

Comment: To expand on Mark's comment: What is $h$ in your formula? Is this a sequence, so that $h=1,2,3,\ldots$?

Comment: In general, to prove that lim sup (whatever) is less than or equal to (something), it suffices to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$, eventually (whatever) is less than (something + $\epsilon$). Here "eventually" means when $h$ is sufficiently large, if you want $h\to\infty$, or else $|h-a|$ is sufficiently small, if you want $h\to a$.

Answer (score 8):

The general statement
$$
A\subset B\Rightarrow\sup\limits_{x\in A}f(x)\le\sup\limits_{x\in B}f(x)\tag{1}
$$
seems intuitively obvious because the proof is very simple:

> Suppose that $a=\sup\limits_{x\in A}f(x)$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $x_\epsilon\in A$ so that $f(x_\epsilon)>a-\epsilon$. Since $A\subset B$, $x_\epsilon\in B$ and we have that $\sup\limits_{x\in B}f(x)>a-\epsilon$. Because $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we get that
>   $$
> \sup_{x\in B}f(x)\ge a=\sup_{x\in A}f(x)
> $$

Let $A_m=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:n>m\}$, then $\sup\limits_{n>m}f(n)=\sup\limits_{n\in A_m}f(n)$.

Note that
$$
\sup_{n\in A_m}f(n)+\sup_{n\in A_m}g(n)=\sup_{(n_1,n_2)\in A_m\times A_m}f(n_1)+g(n_2)\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\sup_{n\in A_m}f(n)+g(n)=\sup_{\substack{(n_1,n_2)\in A_m\times A_m\\n_1=n_2}}f(n_1)+g(n_2)\tag{3}
$$
and
$$
\{(n_1,n_2)\in A_m\times A_m:n_1=n_2\}\subset A_m\times A_m\tag{4}
$$
$(1)$ and $(4)$ say that $(3)\le(2)$, that is
$$
\sup_{n>m}f(n)+g(n)\le\sup_{n>m}f(n)+\sup_{n>m}g(n)\tag{5}
$$
Now take the $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}$ of both sides of $(5)$ to get
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(n)+g(n)\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(n)+\limsup_{n\to\infty}g(n)\tag{6}
$$

Answer (score 2):

This question would definitely need some more clarification from
OP. (Does he mean limit superior of sequences or of functions?
What is his definition of $\limsup$ and which properties of
$\limsup$ does he already know?)

It is very improbable that he gets back to his question after such
a long time. So I've decided to post some answer, so that the
question is not left unanswered and it can be useful for other
people.

---

If the question is about limit superior of a sequence, i.e.
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} (f(n)+g(n))\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} f(n) + \limsup_{n\to\infty} g(n),$$
where $f,g \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$, then the question was
already answered
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70478/properties-of-liminf-and-limsup-of-sum-of-sequences).

So I'll assume that the question is about the inequality
$$\limsup_{x\to a} (f(x)+g(x))\le \limsup_{x\to a} f(x) + \limsup_{x\to a} g(x),$$
where $f,g \colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $a\in \mathbb
R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$.

Since we know that for any real function $f$
$$\limsup_{x\to a} f(x) = \sup\{ \limsup x_n; (x_n)\text{ is a sequence such that }\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=a \text{ and }
(\forall n\in\mathbb N) x_n\ne a\}$$ we can get this result easily
from the subadditivity of limit superior for sequences.

We know that for every such sequence
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} (f(x_n)+g(x_n))\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) + \limsup_{n\to\infty} g(x_n),$$
and if we apply $\sup$ to both sides of this equation, we get the
desired result.