# Properties of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of sum of sequences: $\limsup s_n + \liminf t_n \leq \limsup (s_n + t_n) \leq \limsup s_n + \limsup t_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ be sequences.

I've noticed this inequality in a few analysis textbooks that I have come across, so I've started to think this can't be a typo:

$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n + \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} t_n \leq \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (s_n + t_n) \leq \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n + \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} t_n$.

I understand the right two-thirds of the equation, and can prove it.  I'm stuck on the far-left third.  I don't understand how that is true.

Comment: **Hint:** $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\; s_n = \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\; [(s_n+t_n)-t_n] \leq \cdots$$ and recall that $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\;(-t_n) = -\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\;t_n.$

Comment: Is this leading towards something like:

$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $s_n = \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $[(s_n+t_n)-t_n] \leq \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(s_n+t_n)-\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $t_n$.  Then I sub in the last part of the inequality for $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $s_n$.

Comment: Related threads: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33888/limsup-x-ny-n-lim-x-n-limsup-y-n http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69391/subadditivity-of-the-limit-superior

Comment: Yes exactly, that was the intention. This reduces the claim to what you could prove. Alternatively, you could of course do as Martin did in his answer below.

Comment: @t.b. But how to prove the identity $\lim\ \sup_{n\to \infty} (-t_{n})=-\lim\ \inf_{n\to \infty}\ t_n$ you mentioned?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Do you know of a good reference or hints for proving the subadditivity of the limit supremum? The OP mentions that he already understood the righmost inequality, but it's something I've really been struggling with and have no idea where to turn to figure it out, and I've been working on it for days. I'm struggling my way through the related questions you posted and thinking that *maybe* I need to use subsequences, but otherwise I'm totally stuck.

Comment: @Michael You can have a look at the book Kaczor-Nowak (and perhaps also some other things mentioned in my answer). But you will certainly find a few posts about that on this site. Just have a look at the questions shown on the right among linked questions. You could also go through the questions taggewd both [limsup+inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limsup-and-liminf%20inequality). Or perhaps [frequent tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limsup-and-liminf?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) in (limsup) tag.

Comment: For example, you can find posts about subadditivity of limsup 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408135/prove-limsup-limits-n-to-infty-a-nb-n-le-limsup-limits-n-to-infty),
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515077/prove-that-limsup-n-to-inftya-nb-n-leq-limsup-n-to-inftya-n-lim),
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450697/clarifying-a-proof-of-limsup-a-nb-n-le-limsup-a-n-limsup-b-n).
(Just randomly picked by clicking on related questions.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the help; I'll poke around and see what I can find.

Comment: BTW [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205346/how-to-prove-these-inequalities-liminfa-n-b-n-leq-liminfa-n-limsup/205349#205349) to a duplicate question offers solution alluded to in t.b.'s hint.

Comment: Is it true that :  if $(s_n)_n$ or $(t_n)_n$ are convergent, then the equality holds in following: $$ \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (s_n + t_n) \leq \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n + \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} t_n$$

Comment: Yes. I've got it. It is an immediate consequence of the main question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I will write only about the first inequality $$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n + \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} t_n \leq \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (s_n + t_n).$$ (You wrote that you can prove the rest.)

By definition, if $\liminf t_n=t$ then for each $\varepsilon>0$ the inequality $t_n>t-\varepsilon$ holds for all but finitely many $n$'s.
For such $n$'s we also have $s_n+t_n>s_n+t-\varepsilon$ and
$$\limsup(s_n+t_n) \ge \limsup (s_n+t-\varepsilon) = t-\varepsilon+ \limsup (s_n).$$
(We have used monotonicity of $\limsup$ and that $\limsup (C+x_n)=C+\limsup x_n$ for any constant $C$.)
Since the above inequality is true for each $\varepsilon>0$, we get that
$$\limsup(s_n+t_n) \ge t + \limsup (s_n)=\liminf t_n+\limsup s_n.$$

**EDIT:** Note that the above proof does not work for $t=-\infty$ (it does not make sense to write $-\infty-\varepsilon$), but in this case the inequality is clear. (Of course, we have to omit indeterminate case $\infty-\infty$, i.e., in this case we assume that $\limsup s_n$ is finite.)

---

Or if you use $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \inf\limits_{k\ge n} x_k$ and 
$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sup\limits_{k\ge n} x_k$ as the definition of limit inferior/superior then you can use
$$\sup_{k\ge n} (x_k+y_k) \ge \sup_{k\ge n} x_k + \inf_{k\ge n} y_k$$
to get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n} (x_k+y_k) \ge \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\ge n} x_k + \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{k\ge n} y_k\\
\limsup_{n\to\infty} (x_n+y_n) \ge \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n + \liminf_{n\to\infty} y_n.$$

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit further into details? Why does the inequality holds for all values of n but finitely number of n's?  Shouldn't it hold by definition for an infinite number of n's? And moreover, why could you say that sn+tn>sn+t−εsn+tn>sn+t−ε  results in
lim sup(sn+tn)≥lim sup(sn+t−ε)

Comment: @S.Peter 1) This is definition of limsup. (To be more precise, one of several definitions which are commonly used.) 2) If $a_n\le b_n$ for all $n$, then $\limsup a_n \le \limsup b_n$. (And if finitely many valued of a sequence are change, limit superior is not influenced by that.)

Comment: You meant that this is the definition of lim inf in? From what I know the definition for both lim inf and lim sup is that there is an inifnitely number of n's that |a_n - L| < \$epsilon. Is your definition coming from this statement? I'm still confused regarding this issue

Comment: @S.Peter See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838490/questions-on-limit-superiors/838595#838595) for the definition of $\limsup$. The limit inferior is defined similarly. (As I mentioned, several definitions are commonly used, all of them are equivalent. But this is what is used in the first part of the post.)

Comment: Okay I understand the definition part. But regarding the (And if finitely many valued of a sequence are change, limit superior is not influenced by that) that you mentioned, isn't it true only when the related sequence is converged? In this question it is possible that it isn't, am I worng?

Comment: @S.Peter If sequence is convergent the then $\limsup x_n=\lim x_n$. However, directly from the definition it can be seen that changing finitely many terms influences neither limit superior nor limit inferior.

Comment: The 7th and 11th row contradict each other, you basically wrote $t-\epsilon+\limsup(s_n) ≥t+\limsup(s_n) $

Comment: @Thatπthere What you wrote in your comment is different from the argument that is actually used in the answer. 
Suppose $A,B\in\mathbb R$. Then
$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(A\ge B-\varepsilon)$ implies $A\ge B$.
And we use this fact for $A=\limsup(s_n+t_n)$ and $B=t+\limsup s_n$.
Feel free to ping me here or in [the calculus chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14150/2024/3/2) if a more detailed explanation is needed.

Answer (score 7):

This is an important result, so I would guess that most books and courses will probably mention it and either give a solution or left it as an exercises.

I'll just give a few links (I will not attempt to write down again what others have already written down - and probably much better - and what can be easily found).

**EDIT:** I apologize for not reading your question thoroughly enough. Most of the links I've given bellow prove only the second inequality. (Which is the easier one and you wrote that you were able to show it yourself.) I've left the remaining links - they might be useful for someone - but I've marked which of them show both inequalities.

**Online:**

- http://www.isibang.ac.in/~creraja/Ana1_11/mex.pdf **Both inequalities are shown here.**
- [Topology Q+A board](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=homework_help_2003;task=show_msg;msg=0731.0001)
- http://www.math.hmc.edu/computing/support/tex/classes/hmcpset/hw-example.pdf
- http://www.math.purdue.edu/~danielli/hmw5(MA504).pdf

**Books:**

- Wieslawa J. Kaczor, Maria T. Nowak: Problems in mathematical analysis: Volume 1; Real Numbers, Sequences and Series, Problem 2.4.15. The problem is given on [p.44](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA44) and solved on [p.198-199](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA198). (AFAIK this book is also available in French and Polish.) **Both inequalities are shown here.** You might also be interested in Problem 2.4.17, where similar result for product of sequences is shown.
- Sterling K. Berberian: A first course in real analysis, [p.54](http://books.google.com/books?id=pvI1DFVgP9UC&pg=PA54). One of the inequalities is given here as an exercise, but a detailed hint is given.
- Jacques Dixmier: [General Topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=eKzXj64JeZoC), Theorem 7.3.7 - this result is given here in a much greater generality - for a limit superior along a filterbase.

**Searches:**

- Some of the web results above were among the first when I tried searching for [limsup sum](http://www.google.com/#q=limsup+sum). Also reasonable ["lim sup" sum](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22lim+sup%22+sum) and  ["limit superior" sum](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22limit+superior%22+sum).
- ["lim sup" "(an bn)" "lim inf"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22lim+sup%22+%22%28an+bn%29%22+liminf)
- ["limsup (xn+yn)"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22limsup%22%28xn+yn%29%22) Again, you can replace limsup by "lim sup" or "limit superior".
- ["lim sup" "(an+bn)"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22lim+sup%22+%22%28an+bn%29%22)
- [limsup subadditive](http://www.google.com/#q=limsup+subadditive)