# proving an inequality involving limit superior and limit inferior

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

how can I show that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} (a_n + b_n) \geq \limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n) + \liminf_{n\to\infty}(b_n)$$

Comment: See also this question: [Properties of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of sum of sequences](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70478/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $\limsup_n (x_n+y_n) \le \limsup_n x_n + \limsup_n y_n$, with $x_n = a_n+b_n$ and $y_n = -b_n$.