# How to prove these inequalities: $\liminf(a_n + b_n) \leq \liminf(a_n) + \limsup(b_n) \leq \limsup(a_n + b_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

The inequalities are:

$$\liminf(a_n + b_n) \leq \liminf(a_n) + \limsup(b_n) \leq \limsup(a_n + b_n)$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Proofs like this are usually easiest done indirectly: Assume "$>$" holds instead of "$\le$". Then the difference is some $\epsilon>0$, ...

Comment: See [Properties of liminf and lmisup of sequences](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70478/properties-of-liminf-and-limsup-of-sum-of-sequences) (and the linked questions and links given there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**: First show that $\limsup$ is subadditive, that is, 
\[
  \limsup(a_n + b_n) \le \limsup a_n + \limsup b_n
\]
for real sequences $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$. From this conclude using $-\limsup(-a_n) = \liminf a_n$ that $\liminf$ is superadditive (inequality $\ge$ in the above). Then you can use all this to prove 
\[ \liminf (a_n + b_n) - \limsup b_n = \liminf (a_n + b_n) + \liminf(-b_n) \le \liminf a_n \]
and the other inequality you need.