# Prove limit of function

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove this limit:

> Given $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}\,$ and $\,f(x)>0,\,$ if $\,\lim_{x\to 0} \left(f(x) + \dfrac{1}{f(x)}\right) = 2,\,$ then $\,\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 1$.

Comment: Is it not rigorous enough to do this by direct substitution?

Comment: @Ovi $f$ has to be continuous for direct substitution to be possible.

Comment: There is an answer well worth reading at a posting that has been closed as a duplicate of this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496603/lim-limits-x-to-afx-frac1fx-2-then-lim-limits-x-to-afx-1

Answer (score 3):

Assume $f(x)$ does not converge towards $1$ when $x\to 0$. That means there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n\to 0$, and $|f(x_n)-1|>\epsilon$ for all $n$, so either $f(x_n)>1+\epsilon$ or $f(x_n)<1-\epsilon$.

Now, notice that the function $g:x\mapsto x+1/x$ admits a strict minimum for $x=1$. That means there exists $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$ such that in both of the above cases, $g(f(x_n))>2+\sigma$, which is impossible, hence the result.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Prove first that there exists some $\delta$ such that $f$ is **positive and bounded** on $(x- \delta, x+ \delta)$.

**Hint 2:**
$$\lim \limits_{x \to a}f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}=2 \Leftrightarrow \\
\lim \limits_{x \to a}(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}-2)=0 \Rightarrow \\
\lim \limits_{x \to a}(f(x)^2-2 f(x)+1)=0 
$$ 
with the last step following from the fact that $f$ is positive and bounded.

Thus
$$\lim \limits_{x \to a}(f(x)-1)^2=0 
$$ 
Tke the square root now.

Comment: How do we know that $1/f$ doesnt go to 0

Comment: Is that even a problem

Comment: @Milan Doesn't matter. Once you show that $f \geq 0$ then for some $\delta_1$ you have $$0 \leq f \leq f+\frac{1}{f} \leq 3$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=\max\{f(x),\frac1{f(x)}\}$ and note that $$\begin{align}h\colon [1,\infty)&\to[2,\infty)\\x&\mapsto x+\frac1x\end{align}$$ is a continous bijection with continuous inverse $$\begin{align}h^{-1}\colon [2,\infty)&\to[1,\infty)\\y&\mapsto \left(\frac{\sqrt{y-2}+\sqrt{y+2}}2\right)^2\end{align}$$ (the square roots ocurring here are $\sqrt x\pm\frac1{\sqrt x}$ because $y\pm 2=x\pm2+\frac1x$).

Since $h(g(x))=f(x)+\frac1{f(x)}\to 2$ as $x\to 0$, we conclude $g(x)\to h^{-1}(2)=1$.
Hence if $\epsilon>0$. Then for $x$ sufficiently close to $1$ we have $g(x)<1+\epsilon$, i.e. $$1-\epsilon=\frac{1-\epsilon^2}{1+\epsilon}<\frac1{1+\epsilon}<f(x)<1+\epsilon.$$
This precisely says that $$\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$, then the first limit can be written as, $z+\dfrac{1}{z}=2$. Equivalently, we can write, $z^2 -2z +1=0$ or $(z-1)^2=0$.

Thus $z=1$ and so $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=1$.

Comment: This assumes that $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}(f(x))$ exists. That's the hard part.

Comment: the function is bounded below. a theorem in analysis affirm that is this situation the limit exists.

Comment: @LeandroTavares Why is it bounded below? And why isn't the limit $0$?

Comment: @ Git Gud because $0 < f(x)$

Comment: @LeandroTavares I missed that hypothesis, but still: $x\overset{]0,+\infty[}{\longrightarrow} \dfrac{1}{x}$ and the limit isn't finite.

Comment: you're right i make a mistake. sorry

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)+\frac1{f(x)}$ might exist even if $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Christian Bueno :$(z-1)^2 = 0 $implies only $z=1$ . you're not using the hipothesis $f(x) > 0$

Comment: @Leandro Whoops, yea just fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let
\begin{align}
&a=\liminf_{x\to 0}f(x)&&b=\limsup_{x\to 0}f(x)
\end{align}
[Since](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/205346)
$$\liminf_{x\to 0}\left(f(x)+\frac 1{f(x)}\right)\leq\liminf_{x\to 0}f(x)+\limsup_{x\to 0}\frac 1{f(x)}\leq\limsup_{x\to 0}\left(f(x)+\frac 1{f(x)}\right)$$
we get
$$2\leq a+\frac 1a\leq 2$$
from which $a=1$.
Similarly, $b=1$, hence $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $c(x) = f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$.  Solve a quadratic equation to see that
$f(x)$ is either $(c(x)+\sqrt{c(x)^2-4}\;)/2$ or $(c(x)-\sqrt{c(x)^2-4}\;)/2$ .  So, for all $x$, we have
$$
\frac{c(x)-\sqrt{c(x)^2-4}}{2} \le f(x) \le \frac{c(x)+\sqrt{c(x)^2-4}}{2}
$$
But we are told that $\lim c(x) = 2$, so that
$$
\lim \frac{c(x)-\sqrt{c(x)^2-4}}{2} = 1\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{c(x)+\sqrt{c(x)^2-4}}{2} = 1.
$$
Our function $f(x)$ is between these, so $\lim f(x) = 1$.

Comment: A variant of this works even if we allow $f$ to have complex values.

Comment: You have to prove $c(x)\geq 2$ in a neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: In fact, $u+\frac{1}{u} \ge 2$ for all reals $u$.