# If $\lim \limits_{x \to a}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=2,$ then $\lim \limits_{x \to a}f(x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $f:(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\to(0,\infty).$
>
> If $$\lim \limits_{x \to a}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=2,$$
> prove that  $$\lim \limits_{x \to a}f(x)=1.$$

I'm trying to get something using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition but I'm stuck . How to use $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ information I'm wondering .

$$~~$$
An [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3496623/503397)

Comment: @Fimpellizieri no

Comment: It makes sense to speak of the limit at $a$ only if $f$ is defined in a neighborhood of $a$, so the information $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ is not particularly useful besides making sure that trying to compute limits makes sense in the first place.

Comment: Then i am out of ideas. Maybe you are right, it should have been said assuming the limit exists.

Answer (score 5):

The assumption implies that $$\lim_{x\to a} \left(\sqrt{f(x)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{ f(x)}}\right)^2=0,$$ hence $$\lim_{x\to a} \sqrt{f(x)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{ f(x)}}=0.$$ Similarly, $$\lim_{x\to a} \left(\sqrt{f(x)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ f(x)}}\right)^2=4,$$ hence $$\lim_{x\to a} \sqrt{f(x)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{f(x)}}=2.$$ Summing up and dividing by two we obtain $$\lim_{x\to a} \sqrt{f(x)}=1,$$ hence $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=1.$$

Comment: This is clever! I like it. +1

Comment: What a coincidence, we have done the same in our practices a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a local inverse around 1 to $g(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ by solving quadratic formula. Then use the continuity of said inverse to find the epsilon and delta you need.

Call this inverse $h$. Then, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x))$

So, by continuity of $h$, $$1=h(2)=h(\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x)))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$

Comment: Why around 1? I don't understand

Comment: You can only invert locally because of the square root you will take. Around one as we will want to show $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=1$