# Prove $\liminf(a_n + b_n) \le a + B$ (Using "$\varepsilon$ language")

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

> Denote: $\liminf a_n = a$ and $\limsup b_n = B$.
>   Prove: $\liminf(a_n + b_n) \le a+B$.

The proof:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$.
By definition of infimum, there's a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $a_{n_k} \le a +\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

By definition of supremum, there's a subsequence $b_{n_k}$ such that $b_{n_k} \le B +\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

Hence, (for sufficiently large $n_k$):
$$(a_{n_k} + b_{n_k}) \le a + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + B + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = a+ B + \varepsilon$$

Therefore, 
$$\liminf (a_{n_k} + b_{n_k}) \le a+ B$$

And that's implying:

$$\color{Green}{\liminf (a_n + b_n) \le a+ B}$$

I'd be glad to get an explanation for the "Green" claim.

Is it because $a_{n_k} + b_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $a_n + b_n$?

Comment: Where did you find this proof?

Comment: It's not from a book. It's someone's work I got my hands on :)

Comment: I don't see why they can claim that the two subsequences $a_{n_{k}}$ and $b_{n_{k}}$ have the same subscripts.

Comment: You might find this link helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475484/addition-inequalities-with-lim-sup-and-lim-inf

Comment: That might be useful, but I want to prove it using $\varepsilon$-language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof:

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then some $k$ exists with $n>k\Rightarrow b_{n}\leq B+\varepsilon$.

Then $a_{n}+b_{n}\leq a_{n}+B+\varepsilon$ for $n>k$ and consequently
$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(a_{n}+b_{n}\right)\leq a+B+\varepsilon$.

This is true for any $\varepsilon>0$ and this allows the conclusion
that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(a_{n}+b_{n}\right)\leq a+B$.

Comment: I understand your approach. But given $\liminf(a_{n_k} + b_{n_k}) < a + B$. How to conclude $\liminf(a_n + b_n) < a + B$?

Comment: If $(c_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(c_n)$ then $\liminf c_n\leq \liminf c_{n_k}$. For every $d<\liminf c_n$ you have $c_{n_k}>d$ for $k$ large enough so $\liminf c_{n_k}\geq d$. Consequently $\liminf c_{n_k}\geq \liminf c_n$.