# Prove that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(a_n + b_n \right) \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n +\limsup_{n \to \infty} b_n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, self-learning

I want to prove that for two sequences, say $a_k$ and $b_k:$

$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(a_n + b_n \right) \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n +\limsup_{n \to \infty} b_n$$

If we let $M_n =\sup \{ a_k : k \geq n \}$ and $N_n = \sup \{ b_k : k\geq n  \} $, then obviously

$$a_k +b_k \leq M_n+ N_n \Leftrightarrow  \sup \{a_k+b_k: k \geq n \} \leq M_n + N_n$$

After that, the order limit theorem should suffice, right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct +1. I made a few cosmetic changes, I hope it's ok.

Comment: @julien They are welcome, thank you.

Comment: About your rollback. To denote the [limsup of a sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) $x_n$, you are supposed to write $\limsup_{n\rightarrow +\infty} x_n$ and not $\limsup_{n\rightarrow +\infty} x_k$. Indices should be the same, otherwise it would mean that the sequence is constant.

Comment: @julien Rewrote it, thanks.

Comment: There are a few other posts on this, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408135/prove-limsup-limits-n-to-infty-a-nb-n-le-limsup-limits-n-to-infty) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/408135).

Comment: At the part where you said obviously, why is that obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined $M_n$ and $N_n$ and you know that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}M_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\quad\text{and}\quad
\lim_{n\to\infty}N_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n.
$$
Next let
$$
P_n=\sup\{a_k+b_k: k\ge n\}, \quad\text{and likewise}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}P_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n).
$$
As you have noticed 
$$
P_n\le M_n+N_n.
$$ 
Taking the limit in the above you are done.

Comment: Why is $P_n\le M_n+N_n$

Comment: @Thatπthere You could have a look at: [Supremum of sum of two sequences: $\sup (x_n+y_n) \le \sup x_n + \sup y_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/930695)