# Prove that $\limsup(a+b) \leq \limsup(a) + \limsup(b)$ and $\liminf(a+b) \geq \liminf(a) + \liminf(b)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Prove that $$\limsup(a+b) \leq \limsup(a) + \limsup(b)$$ and $$\liminf(a+b) \geq \liminf(a) + \liminf(b)$$ where $a,b:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ are two bounded sequences.

I'm not sure where to begin on this proof.

Comment: You should begin by writing down the definitions of $\lim \sup (a+b)$, $\lim \sup(a)$, and $\lim \sup(b)$

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate. Have you checked the related questions?

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408135/prove-limsup-limits-n-to-infty-a-nb-n-le-limsup-limits-n-to-infty) (and other [posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/408135)) and maybe also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70478/properties-of-liminf-and-limsup-of-sum-of-sequences-limsup-s-n-limin) (and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/70478)

Comment: Apart from Alexis Olson's suggestion to check related questions, another easy way to find posts about this inequality is to check question tagged [limsup+inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limsup-and-liminf+inequality) and then choose the [frequent tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limsup-and-liminf+inequality?sort=frequent).