# If $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are bounded sequences, then $\text{lim sup}\{x_n + y_n\} \leq \text{lim sup}\{x_n\} + \text{lim sup} \{y_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

my question is as follows:

> If $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are bounded sequences, then $$\text{lim sup}\{x_n + y_n\} \leq  \text{lim sup}\{x_n\} + \text{lim sup} \{y_n\}$$

I know that $\text{lim sup} \{x_n\}$ is the supremum of the set of all subsequential limits of $\{x_n\}$. I want to work with this definition.

How should I proceed with this definition?

Comment: Try taking an arbitrary converging subsequence of $\{x_n + y_n\}$, say $x_{n_j} + y_{n_j}$, and then use the natural bounds given by $\limsup \{x_n\}$ and $\limsup \{y_n\}$. You will need to take limits in the process. Conclude by using the fact that the supremum is the lowest upper bound.

Comment: Duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408135/prove-limsup-limits-n-to-infty-a-nb-n-le-limsup-limits-n-to-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n+b_n) \le \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n + \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408135/prove-limsup-limits-n-to-infty-a-nb-n-le-limsup-limits-n-to-infty)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\limsup(x_n+y_n)>\limsup(x_n)+\limsup(y_n)$. So there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\limsup(x_n+y_n)>\limsup(x_n)+\limsup(y_n)+\varepsilon$, and by definition, there exists a subsequence $(x_{\varphi(n)}+y_{\varphi(n)})_n$ of $(x_n+y_n)$ which converges to some $\ell>\limsup(x)+\limsup(y)+\varepsilon$. This implies that for $n$ large enough, $x_{\varphi(n)}+y_{\varphi(n)}>\limsup(x)+\limsup(y)+\varepsilon$. But the latter implies that for $n$ large enough, either $x_{\varphi(n)}>\limsup(x)+\frac12\varepsilon$ or $y_{\varphi(n)}>\limsup(y)+\frac12\varepsilon$ (if none of those two inequalities held, we would not have the former one).

We deduce that either there exist infinitely many integers $n$ such that $x_{\varphi(n)}>\limsup(x)+\frac12\varepsilon$, or there exist infinitely many integers $n$ such that $y_{\varphi(n)}>\limsup(y)+\frac12\varepsilon$. Without loss of generality we can suppose that $x_{\varphi(n)}>\limsup(x)+\frac12\varepsilon$ holds for infinitely many integers $n$. But that would mean that $\limsup((x_{\varphi(n)})_n)\ge\limsup(x_n)_n+\frac12\varepsilon$, which is nonsense since we obviously have $\limsup((x_{\varphi(n)})_n)\le\limsup(x_n)$ (any subsequence of $(x_{\varphi(n)})_n$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)_n$).

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $s_{n}=\sup_{k\geq n}x_{k}$ and
$t_{n}=\sup_{k\geq n}y_{k}$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\geq n$
be arbitrary. Observe that $x_{k}+y_{k}\leq s_{n}+t_{n}$, so $\sup_{k\geq n}(x_{k}+y{}_{k})\leq s_{n}+t_{n}$.
It follows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}(x_{k}+y_{k})\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_{n}+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_{n}$.
That is, $\limsup_{n}(x_{n}+y_{n})\leq\limsup_{n}x_{n}+\limsup_{n}y_{n}$.

Comment: It is more direct to work with the original definition of $\limsup$. That is, $\limsup_n x_n =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup_{k\geq n} x_k$.