# Can anyone give me a hint on how to prove that subadditivty of the limit supremum of two sequences? Everything I can find says "it's trivial."

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

**I'm working through some analysis textbooks on my own, so I don't want the full answer. I'm only looking for a [hint](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11258/93114) on this problem.**

I'm trying to prove the subadditivity of the limit supremum, i.e.

$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} (x_n + y_n) \le \limsup_{n \to \infty} (x_n) + \limsup_{n \to \infty} (y_n)
$$

My book and the notes that accompany it say I should be able to do this without resorting to properties that relate the infimum to the supremum, so I'm assuming my approach shouldn't follow [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70478/93114) (which doesn't actually address this particular statement directly).

Here's my attempt at a proof that uses contradiction:

1. Assume that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (x_n + y_n) > \limsup_{n \to \infty} (x_n) + \limsup_{n \to \infty} (y_n)$
2. Consider the sequences $(x_n) = (-1)^n$ and $(y_n) = (-1)^{n+1}$. I know that $\forall n, \sup(x_n) = \sup(y_n) = 1$, but $\sup(x_n + y_n) = 0$.
3. This is a contradiction because I can't have $0 > 1$, so the proof is complete.

Is this a valid proof for this?

If this isn't a valid proof, is there a simple hint that may put me on the right track? I'm a bit stuck on this one.

---

EDIT:

Here's what I can think of so far, but I'm really stuck on this.

1. I know that the supremums of subsequences form a monotonically decreasing sequence, and because that sequence converges, it's bounded.
2. I know that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (x_n)$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (y_n)$ aren't necessarily upper bounds on the entire sequence; they're just upper bounds on some subsequence *in the limit*.

I'm really at a loss where to go from here. Can anyone give me some nudge in the right direction? After staring at this proof for days and seeing a lot of resources that say "it's trivial" which is pretty disheartening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that the claim is not quite true as stated: you have to exclude the case that 
 $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n = +\infty$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} y_n = -\infty$ or vice versa, in which case the right side is undefined.

Suggestion:

1. Let $a_m = \sup_{n \ge m} (x_n + y_n)$, let $b_m = \sup_{n \ge m} x_n$, $c_m = \sup_{n \ge m} y_n$.  We want to show $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_m \le \lim_{m \to \infty} b_m + \lim_{m \to \infty} c_m$.
2. Note that for any $n \ge m$ we have $x_n \le b_m$ and $y_n \le c_m$.  Conclude that for any $n \ge m$ we have $x_n + y_n \le b_m + c_m$.
3. Show that $a_m \le b_m + c_m$.
4. By standard properties of limits, $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_m \le \lim_{m \to \infty} (b_m + c_m)$.
5. By standard properties of limits, $\lim_{m \to \infty} (b_m + c_m) = \lim_{m \to \infty} b_m + \lim_{m \to \infty} c_m$.  (Note that we have to assume, as I mentioned at the top, that the limit on the right side is not of the form $\infty - \infty$.)

Comment: I sort of follow you until step 3, but here's my thought on #3. Say that this isn't true, and $a_m > b_m + c_m$. I keep wanting to bring this back to the sign of the elements, though, and say something like if $a_m > b_m + c_m$, then $\sup_{n \ge m} (x_n + y_n) > \sup_{n \ge m} x_n + \sup_{n \ge m} y_n$, so at some index $i \ge m$, then the element $x_i + y_i$ exceeds the upper bounds of both sequences put together. That seems intuitively correct, but I don't know how to make it rigorous.

Comment: Obviously step #3 is the meat here, because once we have that everything follows quickly from standard properties of limits.

Comment: Wait, no, I think I have #3 now that we're just talking about the supremums of sets. Since #3 doesn't involve the limits, we're just talking about the supremum of the sets $X = \{x_n | n \ge m\}$ and $Y = \{y_n | n \ge m\}$. If $u = \sup X$ and $v = \sup Y$, then $x \le u, \forall x \in X$ and $y \le Y, \forall y \in Y$, so by addition, $x + y \le u + v, \forall x \in X, y \in Y$. Is that it?

Comment: @Michael: What you've written is actually the logic needed for #2, not #3.  For #3, consider the following: in #2 we showed that $b_m + c_m$ is an upper bound for the set $\{x_n + y_n \mid n \ge m\}$.  And $a_m$ is by definition the *least* upper bound of this set...

Comment: Right, I forgot that last part, but I figured it out. $a_m$ is the least upper bound of the set, so since we found something that's an upper bound of the set, we know $a_m$ has to be $\le$ than it. Then the rest follows from the properties of limits.

Answer (score 1):

You have only given one example of sequences where the opposite statement (sub-additivity fails) is false, by contradiction. A full proof by contradiction would have to consider arbitrary sequences where sub-additivity fails and then somehow derive a contradiction.

Comment: I'm an idiot and obviously I'm been working on this for too long because I didn't even realize that my proof is ridiculous. Thank you. Are these sequences at least an example of sequences where the inequality is strict? Or did I mix something up?

Comment: Yes, your example gives a strict inequality and IMO is a good example.

Comment: Is it straightforward to prove this using contradiction in general, or am I barking up the wrong tree by trying?

Comment: @Michael I think a direct proof is the most straightforward, using properties of lim sup but I may be wrong. Of course you could always turn that into a proof by contradiction by saying "Assume not" and then give the direct proof, giving a contradiction.

Comment: Ok, I'll work on this more. I think the only property I know so far is that the partial supremums form a monotonically decreasing sequence, but I'm not sure where to go from there yet. I really have no idea how to attempt this, and it's pretty frustrating. I don't know that the limit supremum is an upper bound on the entire sequence, so I'm completely stuck. Is there a specific property I should be targeting? I'm sure this is a simple proof, but obviously math isn't my strong suite.