# Showing an inequality of LimSup: $\limsup(x_n+y_n)\geq\limsup(x_n)+\liminf(y_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be sequences of real numbers. Verify that each of the following holds, provided the right-hand side makes sense.
$$\limsup(x_n+y_n)\geq\limsup(x_n)+\liminf(y_n)$$

For this problem we are allowed to assume the following holds:
$$\limsup(x_n+y_n)\leq\limsup(x_n)+\limsup(y_n)$$
$$\limsup(-x_n)=-\liminf(x_n)\text{ and } \liminf(-x_n)=-\limsup(x_n)$$

---

What I've done so far:

See that 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\limsup(x_n)=\limsup(x_n+y_n-y_n) & \leq\limsup(x_n+y_n)+\limsup(-y_n) \\
& = \limsup(x_n+y_n) -\liminf(y_n)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So we obtain
$$\limsup(x_n+y_n)\geq\limsup(x_n)+\liminf(y_n)\text{ as desired.}$$

I feel like this should hold, but I'm curious if this approach covers all potential exceptions. What if we are talking about the extended real numbers? What if $\{y_n\}$ or $\{x_n\}$ diverge?

Comment: When you're working in $\bar{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty \}$, the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of a sequence *always* exist, whether the sequence converges or not. That's part of what makes them so useful.

Comment: So, that is to say on the extended reals, it's not even necessarily a different consideration?

Comment: The only possible problem here in the extended reals is that you can't add $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. A $\limsup$ of a sequence of *real* numbers can never be $-\infty$. So when you write $\limsup(x_n + y_n) + \limsup(-y_n)$, this problem can't occur. You have an inequality $A \leq B + C$, where none of the three numbers is $-\infty$, and you want to conclude that $A - C \leq B$ *provided $A - C$ makes sense*. The inequality is vacuously true if $B$ or $C$ is $+\infty$. The only case left is that $B$ and $C$ are both finite. In that case, $A$ too must be finite.

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70478/properties-of-liminf-and-limsup-of-sum-of-sequences) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/70478)